# Regex for email mask except the first 2 letters and last 2 letters before the @ sign in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a function to mask an email address (except the first 2 letters and the last 2 letters before the `@` sign) but the first 2 letters are still masked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string email = "fajarsyairillah@mail.com";
            string Email = maskEmail(email);
            Console.WriteLine("Email :"+Email);   
        }
        
         public static string maskEmail(string email)
        {
             string pattern = @"[\w-\._\+%a]*(?=[\w]{2}@)";
             string maskedEmail = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(email, pattern, m => new string('*', m.Length));
            return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedEmail) ? email : maskedEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a non-regex approach here, too:

```cs
public static string maskEmailNoregex(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) return email; // Return email back as it is null or empty
    var split = email.Split('@');  // Split with @ char
    if (split.GetLength(0) != 2 || split[0].Length < 5) return email; // There is nothing to modify, return email
    return split[0].Substring(0, 2) + new string('*', split[0].Length-4) + split[0].Substring(split[0].Length - 2) + "@" + split[1];
}
```

If you prefer using a regex, see

```cs
public static string maskEmail(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) return email;
    return Regex.Replace(email, @"(?<=^[^@]{2,})[^@](?=[^@]{2,}@)", "*");
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CWDTwo). Also, see the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B%5E%40%5D%7B2%2C%7D%29%5B%5E%40%5D%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%40%5D%7B2%2C%7D%40%29&i=fajarsyairillah%40mail.com&r=*). Details:

- `(?<=^[^@]{2,})` - a location in string that is immediately preceded with two or more chars other than `@` from the start of the string
- `[^@]` - any char other than `@`
- `(?=[^@]{2,}@)` - a location in string that is immediately followed with any two or more chars other than `@` till a `@` char.